# FTP LIST command hangs in passive mode

Tags: ftp, telnet

Entered ftp server with `anonymous` credentials, and got the response that I logged in successfully `230 Login successful.` Want to list all files in current directory, issued `LIST` command, the server responded that I should enter passive mode first `425 Use PORT or PASV first.`. Entered passive mode with PASV command and got response `227 Entering Passive Mode (204,9,55,82,249,45).`. After that trying to list content of current dirctory with `LIST` command and got nothing in response. However after a minute or so server responded with `425 Failed to establish connection.`. What does this mean? Thanks.

PS. I'm simulating ftp connection with telnet

**UPDATE**
Answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536248/telnet-and-passive-ftp

Comment: There is another way of phrasing this: _I am using something that is not an FTP client and that does not speak the protocol to talk to an FTP server, and I am getting errors with the protocol._  (-:

Comment: I noted that I simulate it with telnet, please read carefully :)

Comment: I already did.  That's the very thing that isn't an FTP client and that does not speak the protocol.  I unburied the lead for you.